# Centralizing My Mac Screen Functionality

Tags: display, screen, resolution

i break my lcd can i centralized the screen/resolution so that i could pick the area i wanted it to show i've tried centralizing it using resolution manager but it just changing the font what i wanted really is moving the edges of the screen in the non cracking area

[image]

Comment: thanks @Thinkr ,@Allan for willing to help